# hide a div when user zoom out on touch screen device

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to hide a div using jQuery when user on touch scale down to original scale

```
var zoom = document.documentElement.clientWidth / window.innerWidth;
    $(window).resize(function(){
        var zoomNew = 
         document.documentElement.clientWidth / window.innerWidth;
        if (zoomNew < zoom){
            galleryZoomOut();
        } 

    });

    function galleryZoomOut() {
        $('#gallery_container').hide();
    }
```

but for some reason is not working

Comment: Do you realley mean "zoom out"? To my understanding this would mean scale to >100%, thus enlarging the Width, while zooming in would mean to take a deeper view on elements (lower than 100%) and thus lower the width. Or am I getting something wrong?

Comment: i mean when user on touch screen want to see the element bigger then the users uses 2 fingers to enlarge width and height , and when the user want this element smaller then the user uses to fingers to zoom in / scale down 
what i'm trying to do when the user scale down / zoom out  till the original size of the element then hide that element /div